# get xml namespace for each node in php

Tags: php, xml

For a given xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<College xmlns:A1="zool:"xmlns:A12="dym:">
    <A1:name>Seattle</A1:name>
    <A1:MiddleName>I</A1:MiddleName>
    <A12:lastname>Roya Asbari</A12:lastname>
</College>
```

how do i get the name space for each node while iterating.

Also the format of xml would differ everytime, so I am m looking for a generic way.

Comment: @Gordon.....getnamespace would give the namespaces in my xml...but i need the namespace for each node...like in the above xml, i need zool:-name, zool:-MiddleName, dym:-lastname.

Comment: @Gordon....sure mate....thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup XML

```
$xml = <<< XML
<College xmlns:A1="zool:" xmlns:A12="dym:">
    <A1:name>Seattle</A1:name>
    <A1:MiddleName>I</A1:MiddleName>
    <A12:lastname>Roya Asbari</A12:lastname>
</College>
XML;
```

#### Getting Element Name, Namespace and Prefix with DOM

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadXml($xml, LIBXML_NOERROR);
foreach($dom->documentElement->childNodes as $child)
{
    printf(
        "Name: %s - NS: %s - Prefix: %s\n",
        $child->nodeName,
        $child->namespaceURI,
        $child->prefix
    );
}
```

#### Output ([codepad](http://codepad.org/xG66n1wV))

```
Name: A1:name - NS: zool: - Prefix: A1
Name: A1:MiddleName - NS: zool: - Prefix: A1
Name: A12:lastname - NS: dym: - Prefix: A12
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php